# pip install UnicodeDecodeError on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to pip install couchdb on my Linux Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 20.04) and I am getting the follow error.

```
cc@team5-vm1-2:~$ pip install couchdb
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 74, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 88, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 289, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent
    linux_distribution = distro.linux_distribution()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 125, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 680, in linux_distribution
    self.name() if full_distribution_name else self.id(),
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 718, in name
    name = self.os_release_attr('name') \
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 894, in os_release_attr
    return self._os_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 556, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 933, in _os_release_info
    return self._parse_os_release_content(release_file)
  File "/home/cc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 964, in _parse_os_release_content
    tokens = list(lexer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I've tried the results for `locale` and this is the returning results and it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

```
cc@team5-vm1-2:~$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Looks like your system is reporting the Linux distribution as a Latin-1 string with ™ in it.

Comment: @BoarGules I am not sure how I can fix that though or why my system is reporting the given Latin-1 string.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling and purging python3 and pip, using autoremove, then reinstall python3 and pip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).